# if statement not executing action even though condition is met

Tags: javascript, if-statement, classname

I'm trying to change the class of an element based on some conditions.

```
const pwnButtonHidden = document.querySelector(".pwn-button-hidden");
let condition = 0;

for (let idNumber = 1; idNumber < 13; idNumber++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document
      .getElementById(`btn-${idNumber}`)
      .addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        condition++;
        console.log(condition);
        document.getElementById(`product-${idNumber}`).className =
          "product-fake";
        document.getElementById(`btn-${idNumber}`).disabled = true;
        document
          .getElementById(`btn-${idNumber}`)
          .removeEventListener("mouseenter", selectSfx, true);
      });
    if (condition >= 12) {
      pwnButtonHidden.className = "pwn-button";
    }
  }, 4000);
}
```

As you can see, at every click condition is augmented by 1. However, even when it reaches 12 (verified by console.log(condition)), it doesn't trigger the class change. How can I fix this?

Tried changing the number of the condition.

Comment: you should inspect in your browser and look at the elements tab to see what is actually happening

Comment: The if statement is put inside the setTimeout. Do you want to check if the buttons were clicked 12 times in total in the span of 4 seconds? If not, consider putting the if statement elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing the condition is happening outside of the `click` event handler. So it's only being checked one time for each loop iteration right when the 4 second delay times out. The code is relocated below.

```
...
        .removeEventListener("mouseenter", selectSfx, true);
      if (condition >= 12) {
        pwnButtonHidden.className = "pwn-button";
      }
      });
  }, 4000);
}
```